# Invalid handle error when calling MQQueueManager constructor in .NET C#

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I've got a seemingly random "The handle is invalid" error when calling the following piece of code :

```
var properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "MyHost");
properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, "MyPort");
properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "MyChannel");

this.QueueManager = new MQQueueManager("MyName", properties);
```

The environment is .NET Framework 3.5 & MQ Client 7.1

The problem is that this error doesn't occur repeatedly, maybe just 15% of the time, only in the production environment, and I can't seem to reproduce it within my development environment. The only trail I've got is that I know than it is possible for this code to be called simultaneously by two different processes. If it helps, I've also got the following stack trace :

```
Win32Exception - The handle is invalid
   at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Modules()
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ.MQCONNX(String pQMgrName, MQCNO& pConnectOpts, Hconn parentHconn, Phconn phconn, Int32& pCompCode, Int32& pReason)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ.MQCONNX(String pQMgrName, MQConnectOptions pConnectOpts, Phconn phconn, Int32& pCompCode, Int32& pReason)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.Connect(String queueManagerName)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..ctor(String queueManagerName, Hashtable properties)
   ...
```

Any ideas ? Anyone ? :)

Answer (score 0):

This [fix](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC90674) might be of help to you. Have you downloaded the latest MQ Client for [v7.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24031412)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, besides the fact that it is a v7.1 client, I don't have any other information about the version installed on site. As it's complicated to have any information (at all...) with this client, we will look at it on our next maintenance phase.